# How to invoke PHP form fields validation only after the "send form" button has been pressed?

Tags: php

I am new to PHP

I wrote this simple online form in PHP and HTML (form.php):

```
<?php 
$errors = array();
$missing = array();
if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
    $to = 'david@example.com';
    $subject = 'Feedback from contact form';
    $expected = array('name', 'email', 'comments');
    $required = array('name', 'comments');
    require './includes/mail_process.php';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Contact Us</title>
<link href="../styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<h1>Contact Us</h1>
<?php if ($errors || $missing) { ?>
<p class="warning">Please fix the item(s) indicated.</p>
<?php }?>
<form name="contact" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <p>
        <label for="name">Name:
        <?php if ($missing && in_array('name', $missing)) { ?>
        <span class="warning">Please enter your name</span>
        <?php } ?>
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="email">Email:
        <?php if ($missing && in_array('email', $missing)) { ?>
        <span class="warning">Please enter your email address</span>
        <?php } ?>
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="comments">Comments:
        <?php if ($missing && in_array('comments', $missing)) { ?>
        <span class="warning">You forgot to add your comments</span>
        <?php } ?>
        </label>
        <textarea name="comments" id="comments"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Send Comments">
    </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, there are 2 main php sections: 
The upper one which

- initialize two arrays
- checks if the "send" button was clicked.
- if "send" button has been clicked, process the form.

The lower one which includes all the if statements in the "body" section.

When I run the form.php, page shows I see 3 fields and a "send" button.

Does this mean, that at this point, the PHP IF statements (in the "body" section) were processed, and each returned false, and this is why I dont see the error messages printed on screen?

OR

The if statements (in the "body" section) are processed only after clicking the "send" button?

Same question for the initialization of the "errors" and "missing" array -> are those initialized as soon as I run the form.php file and see 3 fields and a "send" button, or the upper PHP section runs for the 1st time only after I click on the "send" button?

**To summarize, when I run the form.php, does the page is processed "top to bottom, line by line" or is there a different control flow (because after I click the "send button", the upper PHP section is invoked also so please clarify).**

**Re-Edit:** When page first loads, multiple PHP if statements are being processed for nothing. Correct? is there a way to make it more optimal? Assume 1 million users visit the page for the 1st time (before filling the form), then these if statements are going to be processed 1 million time for nothing. **Isn`t is a bad thing from performance perspective?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PHP does not differentiate between "before" and "after" pressing a button. Does that answer your question? Sure, it can see if there is "POST"ed informaton or not, but that information may have come from another page, or another website, entirely. The fact that there is "POST"ed information doesn't mean this page is being revisited.

Comment: it ll be executed top to bottom....

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['send']))` is false when the page is loaded via a GET request. When the form button is clicked it will be true, so the code inside will execute.

Comment: But not only the code inside the "if (isset...)" runs, but the WHOLE file runs again. Why is that?

Comment: Which part of the file did you want to run again then? It sounds like you want something like an AJAX call or the like.

Comment: If you don't want the FULL code to run on form submit, then you need to put that code in the else part of the `if (isset...)` code or submit the form to another page.

Comment: All I am saying that is that when page first loads, multiple PHP if statements are being processed for nothing. Correct? is there a way to make it more optimal? isn`t is a bad thing from performance perspective?

Comment: php processes the file top-to-bottom, exactly as you see it displayed.

Comment: If there are things you don't want processed when there is no POSTed data, put those things inside an `if` block. Like I said, PHP doesn't distinguish between being called the first time or the second time. All it knows if there is POSTed data or not.

Comment: You did not answer my question. Assume 1 million users visit the page for the 1st time (before filling the form), then these if statements are going to be processed 1 million time for nothing (because the form is not filled yet). Is there a better way to write the code so that PHP will process the if conditions only AFTER the "send" button has been pressed?

Comment: @Qwerty Yes! Make a plain HTML page that contains the form. Send the form to your PHP file on submit.

Comment: Thanks!!! Finally someone who answered my question :-) Can you please write a code example for that as a comment?

Comment: @Qwerty If that was your question, if wasn't very clear at first. Do you want me to write up an answer?

Comment: Yes, please. I re-edited the question as per your input. Please post an answer with code example of how to send a plain HTML file afte clicking on the "send" button, to the php processing script, and I will accept it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78542/discussion-between-qwerty-and-mr-lister).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barring things like loops and calls to functions the PHP file will be ran top to bottom.

Your form points to the same PHP file that generated it. When you click the send button the full PHP file is ran again.

Comment: Thanks. Why the FULL php file runs again after clicking the "send" button?

Comment: All I am saying that is that when page first loads, multiple PHP if statements are being processed for nothing. Correct? is there a way to make it more optimal? isn`t is a bad thing from performance perspective? Assume 1 million users visit the page for the 1st time (before filling the form), then these if statements are going to be processed 1 million time for nothing.

Comment: The lines are being processed to determine if the form has been submitted. `isset($_POST['send']` checks for a submitted form. Otherwise the PHP script wont know whether it has been submitted or not.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the PHP from running when the form is empty, use a different HTML page for the empty form. Let's say `input.html` and this can be plain HTML, without PHP.

```
<html>
<body>
 <form method="post" action="process-the-input.php">
  <input id="user">
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
 </form>
</body>
```

and the PHP file will be called `process-the-input.php` and will function like the source in your question.

Comment: and then redirect to another page, to prevent resending on refresh. It's a common pattern: form - process - results